# AJAX'ed JS component does not work when script type set to "application/javascript"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using AJAX to pull some HTML components with embedded `JS` script. The pulled content has only `body` tag and is used to replace the `body` of the current page. After the body is replaced, the new `JS` code does not work if script type is set to `application/javascript`. But it works without issue if type is empty or "text/javascript".

Here goes my code.

> index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
        function makeAjaxCall(page) {
            $.get( page, function( data ) {
                console.log(data);
                $("body").html(data);
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    This is HTML1 <br/>
    <button onclick=makeAjaxCall("page2.html")> Pull a page with AJAX. The page has script component with no type attribute </button> <br/>
    <button onclick=makeAjaxCall("page3.html")> Pull a page with AJAX. The page has script component with type=application/javascript </button> <br/>
    <button onclick=makeAjaxCall("page4.html")> Pull a page with AJAX. The page has script component with type=text/javascript </button>
</body>
```

> page2.html

```
<body>
<script>
    function A() {
        alert('Horrayyyy!!! JS working as expected');
    }
</script>
This is a page with no type attribute in script tag. After AJAX pull JS will work. <br/>
<button onclick="A()"> Check if JS works. Ans: It will</button>
```

> page3.html

```
<body>
<script type="application/javascript">
    function B() {
        alert('Horrayyyy!!! JS working as expected');
    }
</script>
This is a page with script type set to "application/javascript". After AJAX pull, JS will not work. <br/>
<button onclick="B()"> Check if JS works. Ans: It won't </button>
```

> page4.html

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function C() {
        alert('Horrayyyy!!! JS working as expected');
    }
</script>
This is a page with script type set to "text/javascript". After AJAX pull, JS will work. <br/>
<button onclick="C()"> Check if JS works. Ans: It will </button>
```

Curious how the type attribute is making a difference here.

Comment: You're using a pretty old version of jQuery.

Comment: I just compared the code in 1.7.1 to 1.9.1, and the part that specifically checks for `text/javascript` is gone in the newer version.

Comment: @Teemu That's not really relevant, since this isn't a JavaScript file, it's a `<script>` element within an HTML file.

Comment: You don't even need a `type` attribute for JavaScript elements, it's the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery 1.7.1 the code that looks for scripts in the returned HTML says:

```
if ( scripts && jQuery.nodeName( ret[i], "script" ) && (!ret[i].type || ret[i].type.toLowerCase() === "text/javascript") )
```

So it only processes a `<script>` as JavaScript if there's no type or the type is specifically `text/javascript`.

The explicit check for `text/javascript` has been removed in later versions (I looked at 1.9.1 and this is no longer there). So if you upgrade to a newer version, the problem should go away.